# Making a string out of a dict in python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dict that looks something like this:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Now, when I make a str out of it using str(d) i get

```
>> "{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}"
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
>> "a=b; c=d; "
```

I created this piece of code that does this:

```
b = ''
for k, v in d.items():
    b += str(k) + '=' + str(v) + '; '
```

Is there a way to achieve the same effect, but doing it with an inline operation or some other neater way, without using the for loop?

Comment: For higher performance you could use: `''.join()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Her is another way using `''.join()`:

```
';'.join(map('='.join, d.items()))
```

Returns:

```
'a=b;c=d'
```

This assumes the last `;` is redundant. If not you could get the "exact" output as this: `''.join([f'{k}={v}; ' for k,v in d.items()])`

---

**Timings:**

```
%timeit ';'.join(map('='.join, d.items()))          #1000000 loops,best of 3: 810 ns per loop
%timeit ';'.join(['='.join(x) for x in d.items()])  #1000000 loops,best of 3: 956 ns per loop
%timeit ';'.join([f'{k}={v}' for k,v in d.items()]) #1000000 loops,best of 3: 872 ns per loop
```

Comment: you don't need those square brackets

Comment: @WalterTross True, but the ''.join() will convert it to a list before operating anyway. Try using %timeit and you might be surprised as the `[]` is actually quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
strd = " ".join("{}={};".format(x, y) for x, y in d.iteritems()) # items() if python3
```

`strd`:

```
"a=b; c=d;"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too attached with `=` sign, you can convert it into a json string

```
import json

json.dumps({'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'})
```

This would work for nested dictionaries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the magic method `__repr__()` to get the string representation of an object:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

d.__repr__()
# {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}

d.__repr__().replace(': ', '=').strip('{}')
# 'a'='b', 'c'='d'
```